# Get return value from stored procedure - LINQ

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I want to get the return value in stored procedure using LINQ, EF. I have seen solutions with T-SQL but that method does not solve the problem. I need to solve it with LINQ.

Return 0 I want to take 1 and -1 according to the result

Stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Login]
    @inTcNu CHAR(11),
    @inPass NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @inIP NVARCHAR(40),
    @rolNu TINYINT OUTPUT,
    @kulNu INT OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT @kulNu = kullaniciID, @rolNu = rolID 
    FROM Kullanici WITH(NOLOCK) 
    WHERE tcNumarasi = @inTcNu AND parola = @inPass;

    IF @rolNu >= 0 AND @kulNu >= 0
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO Oturum (tcNumarasi, oturumIP, parola, oturumZamani, girisBasarili)
        VALUES (@inTcNu, @inIP, @inPass, GETDATE(), 1);

        RETURN 1;
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO Oturum (tcNumarasi, oturumIP, parola, oturumZamani, girisBasarili)
        VALUES (@inTcNu, @inIP, @inPass, GETDATE(), 0);

        RETURN 0;
    END

    RETURN -1;
END
```

C#, LINQ, EF

```
using (var ctx = new ktdbEntities())
{
    var IP = networkUtils.GetIP();
    var rolNu = new ObjectParameter("rolNu", typeof(int));
    var kulNu = new ObjectParameter("kulNu", typeof(int));

    var output = ctx.Login(model.tcNumarasi, model.parola, IP, rolNu, kulNu);

    object value1 = rolNu.Value;
    object value2 = kulNu.Value;
}
```

Comment: In your above code, what is the value of `value1`? `value2`?

Comment: If I do not misread your SProc, it will return either 1 or 0, but never -1, so your problem is either not solvable or too trivial. >ou just have to change -1 with 0 in your SPRoc

Comment: @mjwills The values ​​of the parameters defined as out are kulNuand rolNu

Comment: @Marco 
no. If it is 1, if the operation is successful 0, if it is -1, it is determined as a system error. I want to be able to read these values ​​with linq on c # side. To get the error message according to the response I get.

Comment: Your code will not return -1, no matter what. If it hits the if block it will return 1. Otherwise 0, because the Else block will be executed. `RETURN -1` is unreachable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't return values from Stored Procedure like this. You can pass output parameter to achieve it.

Firstly I modified your sp like this;

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Login]
    @inTcNu CHAR(11),
    @inPass NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @inIP NVARCHAR(40),
    @rolNu TINYINT OUTPUT,
    @kulNu INT OUTPUT,
    @result INT OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT @kulNu = kullaniciID, @rolNu = rolID 
    FROM Kullanici WITH(NOLOCK) 
    WHERE tcNumarasi = @inTcNu AND parola = @inPass;

    IF @rolNu >= 0 AND @kulNu >= 0
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO Oturum (tcNumarasi, oturumIP, parola, oturumZamani, girisBasarili)
        VALUES (@inTcNu, @inIP, @inPass, GETDATE(), 1);

        set @result = 1;
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO Oturum (tcNumarasi, oturumIP, parola, oturumZamani, girisBasarili)
        VALUES (@inTcNu, @inIP, @inPass, GETDATE(), 0);

        set @result = 0;
    END

    set @result = -1;
END
```

And then I couldn't see `ctx.Login` method but I assume that you are executing the stored procedure inside it.

```
using (var ctx = new ktdbEntities())
{
    var IP = networkUtils.GetIP();
    var rolNu = new ObjectParameter("rolNu", typeof(int));
    var kulNu = new ObjectParameter("kulNu", typeof(int));
    var resultParam = new ObjectParameter("result", typeof(int));

    var output = ctx.Login(model.tcNumarasi, model.parola, IP, rolNu, kulNu,resultParam);

    object value1 = rolNu.Value;
    object value2 = kulNu.Value;
    object result = resultParam.Value; //Get output value
}
```